# How to add the forbidden sign on the mouse cursor while drag icons in CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework)?

Tags: chromium-embedded

When I drag an item on the browser, if it is dragged to another window, I want the mouse cursor shows the forbidden sign like this:

[image: Forbidden sign cursor]

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of [IDropTarget::DragOver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680129(v=vs.85).aspx) check if you allow your drop (according to your "another window" rule) then change the cursor with this:

```
HRESULT MyIDropTarget::DragOver(DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect)
{
    if (allow_drop_in_this_window)
        *pdwEffect = DropEffect(grfKeyState, pt, *pdwEffect);
    else
        *pdwEffect = DROPEFFECT_NONE;

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I think you answer is for windows platform. How can I do this on CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework)?

Comment: I'm using that C++ code along with CEF3. Which CEF are you using? (add the relative tag please)

Comment: In CEF3 my best bet would be CefDragHandler::OnDragEnter. 
Use CefRefPtr<CefDragData> dragData and DragOperationMask mask arguments. You need to implement CefClient::GetDragHandler (most likely return this), derive your CefClient class also from CefDragHandler, and implement OnDragEnter similar with the MyIDropTarget above.
In OnDragEnter use CefDragData methods to retrieve what you need, for example, to disable file dragging, call dragData->GetFileName(), and if this returns a non-empty CefString, return true from OnDragEnter to cancel drag event.

Answer (score 1):

There is CefDragHandler class in cef/include. I'm not sure if you can achieve what you need (IDropTarget is the way to go on Windows, true) - the DnD support has been modified in both CEF and Chromium.
[Chrome issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224440) seems still open.